# Subquery Performance - Non Unique Column in Where Clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance

I have two tables

**Table Jobs**

```
[ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [title] [varchar](150) NULL,
    [description] [text] NULL

Table JobSkills
[id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [jobId] [int] NULL,
    [skill] [varchar](150) NULL
```

Shown above partial list of columns.

For table JobSkills I have indexed jobId column, column skill is full text indexed.

I have a stored procedure to get the list of jobs. sort of like this.

```
Select totalItems
,Id,title
from
(
    Select Row_Number() over(Order By 
    CASE WHEN @sortBy Is Not Null AND @sortBy='relevance' 
    THEN 
        SkillMatchRank 
    END DESC
    ,CASE WHEN @sortBy Is Not Null AND @sortBy='date' THEN CreateDate END DESC
    ) As rowNumber
    ,COUNT(*) OVER() as totalItems
    ,ID,createDate,title
    from Jobs J
    OUTER APPLY dbo.GetJobSkillMatchRank(J.ID,@searchKey) As SkillMatchRank
    Where
    --where conditions here
) tempData
where 
rowNumber>=CASE WHEN @startIndex>0 AND @endIndex>0 THEN @startIndex ELSE rowNumber END
AND rowNumber<=CASE WHEN @startIndex>0 AND @endIndex>0 THEN @endIndex ELSE rowNumber END
```

I have created a inline table valued function to get the skill matching rank.

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[GetJobSkillMatchRank] 
(   
@jobId int,
@searchKey varchar(150)
)
RETURNS TABLE 
AS
RETURN 
(

select SUM(ISNULL(JS2.[Rank],0)) as rank 
from FREETEXTTABLE(JobSkills,skill,@searchKey) JS2
Where JS2.[Key] in (Select ID from JobSkills Where jobId=@jobId)

)

GO
```

### Problem

Query runs super slow, more then a minute.

### My observation

For the table valued function if I set jobId=1 (I do have a job with id=1) then it performs super fast as desired.
I understand that jobId is not unique column on JobSkills table.

In this case how could I improve the performance???

Comment: The uniquness of the `JobId` field is the least of  your issues...You are filtering on a function and outer-applying on a UDF.

Comment: You also have what I would consider to be a poor design. Each skill should be in a separate row not lumped together in one varchar field. Then you don't need all the extra hoops you are going around for full text processing. You are violating the first normal form for goodness sakes. Each field should have one and only one piece of data per record.

Comment: If you fix your database normalisation issues, you'll almost certainly solve a huge amount of your performance issues.

Comment: @HLGEM each skills has their own row. i am not sure how I could organize this better. I am open to suggestions.

Comment: If each skill has its own row why do you need to use fulltext search?

Comment: on the actual search result stored procedure, it returns search results based on a weighted rank for job title, job description, and skills for the job. for example 0.4*title rank+0.4*description rank+0.2*skill rank. rows are returned based on the total rank in descending order. other the full text how can I get the matching rank?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UDFs are great in certain cases, but the execution plans don't get cached like sprocs do. If you try using another derived table instead of a function, the query might perform better.

Comment: Excellent thinking. That seem to have done the trick. Thank you!

Comment: @manik: If you don't mind, can you mark as answer if you're all set?